# How to use a custom tcp encoder/decoder in spring xd

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-xd

Documentation shows how to use a small set of tcp decoders/ encoders (CR,LF, a few others )
I've got payloads separated by 2 bytes  0x1C 0x0D.
What's the easiest way to specify this in the stream definition ?
Or will I have to create a custom source/sink as shown here?
http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/0.1.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/creating-a-sink-module.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoders are used in `source`s, not `sink`s; sinks use encoders.

Yes, you need to customize the source/sink.

Please use a newer version of XD than 0.1.x; the current release is 1.2.0.

See the [Spring Integration documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#connection-factories) about creating custom encoders/decoders (usually based on the `AbstractByteArraySerializer`).

Comment: Should have been more detailed , I will need both encoder and decoder;